# How do I make sure the replacement switch for a device can handle the power demands?

Tags: amperage, component-selection

My 10 year old (out of warranty which ends at 8 years) blender on off switch broke. The unit still runs great, I don't want to trash it. I just need to replace the switch. But I don't know what kind of switch it is. The switch is not labeled, and Blendtec doesn't sell replacements. I have reached out to them for the part or model number to no avail.

[Found this site where other users had the same issue and were asking about the switch but there are no answers.](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/184294/Whats+the+model+number+of+the+switch)

Found [this StackExchange question about a labeled switch being able to handle the power/current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/527913/how-do-i-determine-whether-a-switch-can-handle-the-power-current-in-a-circuit) but my switch isn't labeled.

My question, **is there a way to calculate how much energy the appliance would draw from its label, and the calculate what type of switch would be safe to use with it?**

The label on the blender says:
50-60Hz
120 a.c.
1560 WATTS

Comment: 1560 Watts at 120 VAC is 13 A.  Find a switch rated at 13 A (or better yet 15 A for some margin) and 120 VAC and you should be OK.  You can search on digikey.com or even Amazon.

Comment: Isn't there 10 or 11 switches and 1 Triac. If nothing works, it's probably the triac

Comment: It's a blender, not an arc welder.  Find something thats got proper voltage rating (125 or 250VAC), and fits mechanically and just use it.  Buy a couple spares if you're worried about it.

Answer (score 2):

Others have reported success with [Carlingswitch 901](https://www.carlingtech.com/sites/default/files/documents/R-Series_Details_%26_COS_0.pdf) series switches, which are easily available. They are rated at 16A/125VAC but, more importantly, 3/4 HP, so they should be fine for a switching a small motor load like a blender. Image from Digikey.ca.

[image]

Suggest you refer to the above-linked datasheet and compare the dimensions with the switch you have (preferably using calipers). The rest of the part number after 901 specifies mostly cosmetic color and actuator shape details. Eg. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VbtM.png

Comment: 1560W  is about three times 3/4HP

Comment: @Jasen They claim 3 "peak HP", for marketing purposes anyway. But the presence of  a motor rating (along with the 16A resistive rating) gives me confidence.